# multi-row multi-value update in a MySQL transaction

Tags: mysql

I am using innodb tables in MySQL.  I want to update several rows in a table, with each row getting a different value, e.g.:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 SET
   col1=3  WHERE id=25,
   col1=5  WHERE id=26
```

In Postgres I believe this is possible:

```
UPDATE tbl_1 SET col1 = t.col1 FROM (VALUES
        (25, 3)
        (26, 5)
) AS t(id, col1)
WHERE tbl_1.id = t.id;
```

How do you do this efficiently and effectively in a transaction?

Issues I hit so far:

- using an intermediate temporary MEMORY table turns out to not be transaction safe
- using a TEMPORARY table - persumably MEMORY type again - is virtually undocumented and I can find no real explanation of how it works and how well it works in my case, for example any discussion on whether the table is truncated after each transaction on the session
- using an InnoDB table as a temporary table and filling, joining to update and then truncating it in the transaction seems a very expensive thing to do; I've been fighting MySQL's poor throughput enough as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you update with a case and set value for `col1` depending on `id`

```
UPDATE tbl_1 SET col1=CASE id WHEN 25 THEN 3 WHEN 26 THEN 5 END WHERE id IN (25,26)
```

Comment: any idea of the efficiency of this?

Comment: shouldn't be a problem (expecting you would not replace thousands of rows - that would result only in a very huge statement), because you're filtering with a `WHERE` clause, so MySQL has to select only these two rows (the `CASE` statement isn't the problem here)

Comment: ~3K rows at each time; with a temp table it takes a second, no more.  And then I discover - after crashes - that MEMORY temp tables are not transaction safe. :( wtf fed up with mysql

Comment: hum, could you give a try to my solution? I think it should take much longer than your temp table solution

Comment: I can get ~5K rows per second with the case statement.  Thx

Comment: Thanks :) I meant it should NOT take longer than your temp table ^^